# incompatible types - found java.util.Iterator(Lot) but expected java.util.Iterator (java.lang.String)

Tags: java

I'm currently having a problem to iterate over a collection. When I declare the fields and constructor and try to enter my method to iterate over the collection and print out the elements, it comes up with the following error.

incompatible types - found java.util.Iterator(Lot) but expected java.util.Iterator (java.lang.String)

Here is my code.

```
public class Auction
{
// The list of Lots in this auction.
private ArrayList<Lot> lots;
// The number that will be given to the next lot entered
// into this auction.
private int nextLotNumber;

/**
 * Create a new auction.
 */
public Auction()
{
    lots = new ArrayList<Lot>();
    nextLotNumber = 1;
}
public void close ()
{
    Iterator<String> it = lots.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(it.next());
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
public void close ()
{
    Iterator<Lot> it = lots.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Comment: Class `Lot` should implement `toString()`.

Comment: @Zecc its not necessary it will invoke Object's toString(), ofcourse if it overrides its good